# F# Pattern Matching elements in a tuple

Tags: f#

I am trying to test the equality of the elements in a tuple of type char using pattern matching as follows:

```
let swap (x,y) =
match fst(x,y) with
| snd(x,y) -> (x,y)
| _ -> (y,x);;
```

and receive the following error: `stdin(11,8): error FS0039: The pattern discriminator 'snd' is not defined`

Please note, I have already discovered a better way to solve the actual problem.  I am just curious why this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Aside - `match fst(x,y) with` can be written as `match x with` much more elegantly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work, because `snd(x,y)` is not a supported pattern. You can see the whole table here: [Pattern Matching (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx).

You could use *variable pattern* instead and check for equality after `when`:

```
match x, y with
| x, y when x = y -> (x,y)
| _ -> (y,x);;
```

but in this case it's probably better to use `if .. then .. else`:

```
if x = y then (x,y) else (y,x)
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you cannot use a function in match pattern. You can use pattern matching like this:

```
let swap (x, y) =
    match x = y with
    | true -> (x, y)
    | _ -> (y, x)
```

or just use simple if expression:

```
let swap (x, y) = if x = y then (x, y) else (y, x)
```